# What is the reference for Hep C saving Morty and Co from Hep A?

Tags: rick-and-morty

What is the reference for [Hep C] saving Morty and Co from Hep A in the "Anatomy Park" episode? I'm sure there has to be a scientific or cultural reference here, so what is it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In terms of scene framing, Hep A and Hep C is supposed to look somewhat similar to the final climatic scene of *Jurassic Park* where the T-Rex snatches up the small raptor mid-jump.

In the *Rick and Morty* scene, the action plays out almost identically.

Comment: This gets the movie reference, but it doesn't answer the "why Hep C" part. I'd assume there's some medical joke going on here (does Hep C ever help rather than hinder humans?), but so far I've never seen an answer addressing this part of the joke.

Comment: @DavidS - It's possible, of course, that the writers were just going for the JP joke, and picked Hep A and Hep C as diseases that might exist in the human body (or at least, in *that* human's body)

Comment: I believe Morty is just calling (comedic) attention to the plot hole that's present in the movie being referenced.  I do not have a great immediate memory of Jurassic Park, so I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Abyan is not completely right. Hepatitis D is known to infect only people infected by Hep B, you mixed up the viruses a bit.

Hep C is known to chronify and often leads to severe liver diseases like cirrhosis and/or hepatic carcinoma - so really no good guy here.

Maybe it's meant to be kinda sarcastic. Hep C is transmitted via needle sharing or infected piercing/tattoo needles. But that would be a very poor reference in my opinion and not appropriate for Rick & Morty (and the composition of the joke itself) so I hope there is a better explanation.

My source is a german website for medical students called Amboss.com.
Two direct quotes for google translate:

"Infektion mit dem Hepatitis-D-Virus (HDV), die nur als Super- oder Simultaninfektion mit einer Hepatitis-B-Infektion möglich ist, da HDV das HBsAg zur Replikation benötigt. Ca. 5% aller chronisch HBV-Infizierten sind auch Träger des HDV bei identischen Übertragungswegen: sexuell, parenteral und perinatal. Der Verlauf der Hepatitis D ist abhängig vom Status der Hepatitis B, verläuft jedoch nur selten fulminant mit akutem Leberversagen." (https://next.amboss.com/de/search/hepatitis%20d 16.11.2020)

"Infektionsweg: Bei ca. 40% der Hepatitis-C-Fälle ist die Infektionsquelle bzw. der Infektionsweg nicht bekannt (sporadische Infektion)
Parenteral
Gemeinsam genutzte Injektionsnadeln bei Drogenabhängigen („needle sharing“)
Kontaminierte Nadeln beim Piercen oder Tätowieren
Nadelstichverletzungen (bei medizinischem Personal)
Organtransplantation, Hämodialyse, Bluttransfusionen
Vertikale Infektion: Bei virämischer Mutter sind in Deutschland ca. 5% vertikale Infektionen beschrieben
Sexuell: Untergeordnete Bedeutung bei HCV (im Vergleich zu HBV und HIV) "
(https://next.amboss.com/de/article/lS0v-2#Zea41d9f610b41c8bcb1377f59e4ff96b 16.11.2020)

Everything should also be mentioned here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepatitis_C

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepatitis_D

I would be really glad if someone had a better approach!
Cheers

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  First, it would be far better if you quoted English Wikipedia for those details rather than a German source.  (The wiki page for HDV has virtually identical content, describing co- and super-infections of HBV, effect on outcomes, etc.)  More importantly, however, this has wandered off from the point of the question of the meaning of "HepA" and "HepC" in the episode, since we're now talking about B and D.  Can you substantiate that they simply got the names wrong?  (Especially since the relationship between B and D is _not_ comparable to the dinosaurs.)

Answer (score -1):

think the joke is hepC is a virophage for hepA: basically HepC virus infects only people who have HepA and it makes HepA infection less successful.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This might make sense if it's true; you can make this answer better by citing a reference for that.